# Self-contained proof of Jensen's inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, reference-request, convex-analysis, contest-math

Is it possible anybody could supply a self-contained proof of the following reincarnation of Jensen's inequality? I couldn't manage to find a good one I liked anywhere$\ldots$

> If $f$ is convex and $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, then$$f\left({1\over n} \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i\right) \le {1\over n} \sum_{i = 1}^n f(a_i).$$

Comment: Induction and definition of convex functions?

Comment: What's wrong with the classical induction proof e.g. [Jensen's inequality - Proof 1 (finite form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_1_.28finite_form.29).

Comment: You can use induction on $n$ to prove that if $\sum_1^n p_i=1$, then $f\big( \sum_1^n p_ix_i \big) \leq \sum_1^n p_if(x_i)$.

Comment: So we need to find what you like better?